# VB.NET Delete Webbrowser1 cookies

Tags: vb.net, cookies

How can i delete a webbrowser1 cookies? from a button press

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `webbrowser` control is just an Internet Explorer wrapper so cookies are common to all `webbrowser` controls and Internet Explorer itself - someone correct me if I am wrong.

I suppose you could delete all the cookie files in: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies)`

But I doubt you will be able to do this while the webbroswer is loaded.